# Using a trailing dash in a custom HTML Tag

Tags: html

I've been reading about custom HTML tags and how they should **ALWAYS** contain a dash (-).

Now some of the examples I've seen has used a `prefix-name` (ie. '`<x-tagname>`') type format in their custom elements. I don't want to use a prefix, so I'm wondering if using a trailing dash is also valid? I couldn't find any sources on this matter.

For example:

```
<wrapper->
  <profile->
  <!-- Some content -->
  </profile->
</wrapper->
```

Would this be considered valid?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question. Just a thought: one of the points in using composed tags is also to avoid collision. What is the chance that a 3rd party library uses a "wrapper" or "profile" at some point in your code? If you use a simple "wrapper-" instead of "myproject-wrapper" or "wrapper-forsomething"... you "might" end up having some unexpected behavior. Lots of conditional... but it was just a thought ;)

Comment: @TimBourguignon Very interesting, but would it be DRY to have 'myproject' on every custom element? Think about having to write that every time you want to select an element in CSS.

Comment: I'm torn. If your code relies intensively on those tags, it might be overkill to add a long prefix. But on the other hand with autocompletion in most IDEs, some kind of prefix can also be useful to quickly access the tags you want to use. As for a postfix, auto-completion would also make it transparent. I guess you really have to weight in the risk of collision (how often) and the impact of the collision (effects).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that what you want to do is doable. As long as you have a dash - somewhere in the name and as long as it is all lowercase - you are good to go. There is a list of not allowed names that are reserved: 
annotation-xml
color-profile
font-face
font-face-src
font-face-uri
font-face-format
font-face-name
missing-glyph